# Can I retrieve the output of a program, that is running in another terminal and/or run by root as e.g a cronjob?

Tags: ssh, output

1. Just for the sake of the question, say I open a terminal an log into my Linux computer. I run a program that keeps outputting information on my screen, looping. I close the terminal window, and the program shuts down.
2. I set up a cronjob or a startup script that launches the same program as in example 1. The program is looping now, run as root.
3. I open a terminal, and log into my computer through SSH. Can I make a Bash script that retrieves the output of said program, even if it's running somewhere in the background? I mean, is the program "virtually" outputting information (as in example 1)?

Answer (score 0):

The program closes stdout and stderr when it exits.  Looping it as you describe will just cause it to start and exit continuously.  You could look at redirecting stdout and stderr.